# Asp.Net MVC - Redirect to external URL and Post the data from Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement where I need to redirect the user to another external URL from the MVC Action method and also need to post certain data to the external URL. Please suggest the possible options.

Thanks

Comment: post external request using ajax from the view, then redirect to the internal action

Comment: can you share any reference link pls

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that

```
$(function(){

// button handle the action where you want to post data and redirect
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){

 //ajax post to internal action
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("ActionName","Controller"),
      data: json_object_to_post,
      success: function (result) {
           // handle the result here if required
    }
   });

   //redirect to the external action
    window.location.href = "external_url";
  });
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I want to redirect to external URL from Action method and post the data simultaneously.

Comment: it's the same, ajax will post to your action, window.location point to your external url

Comment: I don't want to post to my action....from my action I want to post the data to an external URL and redirect the user to that URL

Comment: in this case, you should use HttpClient to send an HTTP request to the external site from the controller

Comment: how about redirection?

Answer (score -1):

Consider there are two actions:

```
 public ActionResult First()
    {
    //here store the data wither in session or tempdata
    //session["data"]=postdata;
    //temp["data"]=postdata
       return RedirectToAction(“Second”,”ControllerName”);
    }

public ActionResult Second()
{
//check for the session or temp variables
return View();
}
```

In this way you can pass the data from one Url to another